# Display progress in TextView Android

Tags: android, graphics, textview, progress

Hi I have to show progress in the number itself. I have come across Shader, Gradient used in TextView for horizontal multicoloring of the text. Is their any such built in API to paint characters as in the below image?

[image: Sample Progress Percentage Image - MSPaint]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two TextViews, one white and one green in exactly the same position. Set the height of one so that the text is clipped and it only partly covers the other.

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#990000" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_green"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="58dp"
    android:layout_y="77dp"
    android:text="50"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#009900"
    android:textSize="100sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_x="58dp"
    android:layout_y="77dp"
    android:text="50"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="100sp" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need accurate control over the height of white text!!

Comment: I recommend starting with this type of layout and then writing java code to change the white TextView's height.

Comment: I tried, the space between the text and layout top/bottom hinders the calculation.

Comment: I doubt you can get that kind of precision from a TextView. You could instead create a custom view and override onDraw.

Comment: Newbie to android graphics. Any pointers to it would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial on creating custom views, http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html, and you'll want to pay special attention to the Custom Drawing section.

Answer (score 4):

Use the below code to make gradient.

```
int[] color = {Color.DKGRAY,Color.CYAN};
float[] position = {0, 1};
TileMode tile_mode = TileMode.REPEAT;
LinearGradient lin_grad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 35, color, position, tile_mode);
Shader shader_gradient = lin_grad;
your_text_view.getPaint().setShader(shader_gradient); //you can change the gradient colour in textview
```

Comment: Where do we control the height here? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, improving on Arun's answer is this (untested but should work):

```
private void setTextViewShading(TextView view, float percentage) {
    int[] colors = {Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN};
    float floatPerc = percentage / 100;
    float[] position = {0, floatPerc, floatPerc + 0.0001, 1};
    TileMode tileMode = TileMode.REPEAT;
    LinearGradient linGrad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, view.getHeight(), colors, position, tileMode);
    Shader shaderGradient = linGrad;
    view.getPaint().setShader(shaderGradient);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create my own view class that, in `onDraw()`, renders white text using a `StaticLayout`, then sets a `PorterDuffXferMode` mask on the canvas to mask off the area you want to avoid drawing in green.  Save the layer, use another `StaticLayout` to render the text in green then restore the layer with the mask to get the cut off exactly where you want it to be.